# What is known about multi-perfect numbers?

Tags: number-theory, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

It is unknown if odd perfect numbers exist and it is known that the even
 perfect numbers are those of the form $$2^{n-1}(2^n-1)$$, where $2^n-1$
 is a (Mersenne-)prime.

But what is known about the multi-perfect numbers ?

Is it known whether

- for all $k\ge 3$, there is a number $n$ with $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}=k$ ?

  Examples are

  $k=2$ : $6$

  $k=3$ : $120$

  $k=4$ : $30\ 240$

  $k=5$ : $14\ 182\ 439\ 040$

  $k=6$ : $154\ 345\ 556\ 085\ 770\ 649\ 600$
- there are infinite many numbers $n$ such that $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}$
  is an integer $k\ge 3$ ? For $k=2$, this is closely related to the
  Mersenne-prime-conjecture that there are infinite many mersenne
  primes and therefore infinite many perfect numbers.
- How can very large multi-perfect numbers (excluding perfect numbers)
  be constructed ?

Comment: The references here look like a good place to start: http://oeis.org/A007691

Comment: @Peter, I am posting a follow-up answer in a bit.

Comment: From [OEIS sequence A007691](https://oeis.org/A007691), T. D. Noe notes that: "Luca's solution of problem 11090, which proves that for $k>1$ there are an infinite number of $n$ such that $n$ divides $\sigma_k(n)$, does not apply to this sequence. However, it is conjectured that this sequence is also infinite. - T. D. Noe, Nov 04 2007".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [The Multiply Perfect Numbers Page](http://wwwhomes.uni-bielefeld.de/achim/mpn.html), maintained by [Achim Flammenkamp](http://genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/id.php?id=27669), although the date specified at the very bottom of the home page is Jan. 25, 2014 (which I presume, denotes the last time that the page was modified).

You can also check out Ron Sorli's thesis [here](http://hdl.handle.net/2100/275), for a discussion of some algorithms on searching for multiperfect numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer, in response to your second question.

The following appears as *Exercise #9* in *page 226* of the *Seventh Edition* of **David M. Burton's** book, **Elementary Number Theory**:

> If $\sigma(n)=kn$, where $k \geq 3$, then the positive integer $n$ is called a $k$-*perfect number* (sometimes, *multiply perfect*).
>
> For each $k$, it is conjectured that there are only **finitely** many $k$-perfect numbers.  The largest one discovered has $558$ digits and is $9$-perfect.

The *Seventh Edition* of **Burton's** **Elementary Number Theory** is copyrighted year $2011$.

Comment: From [OEIS sequence A007691](https://oeis.org/A007691), T. D. Noe notes that: "Luca's solution of problem 11090, which proves that for $k>1$ there are an infinite number of $n$ such that $n$ divides $\sigma_k(n)$, does not apply to this sequence. However, it is conjectured that this sequence is also infinite. - T. D. Noe, Nov 04 2007".